# An interface can contain or store values?

Tags: java, android

I am an android developer.
Reading some source codes, I came across something I think weird.

```
CharSequence mCharSe;
mCharSe = "hello"; // This works.
```

It is valid code. Right?

Here is what I think weird. I declared an interface called 'myInterface' like below

```
interface myInterface {
    void function();
}
```

In another part, I wrote some codes like this

```
myInterface mInter;
mInter = "hello"; // This doesn't work
```

As far as I know, an Interface is just a set of empty function.

'CharsSequence' is an interface as well as 'myInterface,'

but Why can't 'myInterface' contain String values like 'CharSequence'??

How and where does 'CharSequence' contain or store values even when it is just a 'interface'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it can, but you need to assign the value in the same statement as declaring the variable. interfaces are now also able to contain default methods, so if you say an Interface is just a set of "empty methods", your knowledge is out of date

Comment: Why do you want to assign a CharSequence to a type that is not a CharSequence?

Comment: The Oracle tutorials might help you understand this concept of inheritance: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Answer (score 2):

After a declaration like `CharSequence mCharSe;` the variable can hold (a reference to) any object that implements the interface `CharSequence`. Since `String` implements this interface, you can assign a string object.

In your second example, `String` does not implement `myInterce`, therefore the assignment is invalid.

Your wording is also slightly incorrect. An interface does not store anything.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is not a set of empty function its **Blue print of a Class**. Below are some points about interface.
1. All the global variable are by default `public` and `final`.
2. All the non static method are `public` and `abstract`. Method bodies exist only for default methods and static methods
For your problem .
There is no link between `String` and your interface.

```
myInterce mInter;
mInter = "hello";
```

This will not work(Compile error).

Whereas `String` `implements` `CharSequence`.See.

```
public final class String
implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

So its already a child of `CharSequence` thats why your first check will work .

Comment: All the method(s) are public and abstract. That was the case a few versions of Java ago. There are default methods that can be used now

Comment: Yeah thx for pointing out. Edit it with proper definition pls . Thx